# Facebook Real-Time Updates user notifications subscription

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I am trying to configure my Facebook app to subscribe to a user's notifications.
I am getting an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error occurred",
    "type": "FacebookApiException",
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 1929002,
    "fbtrace_id": "F9qp3C16CGP"
  }
}
```

My post request has the following format:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{appid}/subscriptions?access_token={appid}|{appsecret}
```

body of request is:

```
{
   "object" : "user",
   "callback_url" : "{callbackurl}",
   "fields" : "notifications",
   "verify_token" : "{verification token}"
}
```

The same post works if I change the "object" to "page" and the "fields" to "notifications"

Anyone  any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can see, and reading the official documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/subscriptions) the only weird thing I could see on your POST request (I hope you're doing this with POST) is that the fields field should be an array of strings, instead of a string.